# How to disable springSecurityFilterChain in test case?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-contract

Hi I have a spring project that has spring security to authenticate users using OAUTH provider, and I have to use Spring Cloud Contract to build up a mock server for consumer testing.

repo: https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/spring-cloud-contract-poc/blob/main/order-service/src/test/java/com/example/producer/BaseClass.java

When I run `./gradlew clean :order-service:contractTest`. The following error is thrown

```
delegate cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: delegate cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.
```

If you look at my SecurityConfig

https://github.com/Isaacwhyuenac/spring-cloud-contract-poc/blob/main/order-service/src/main/java/com/example/producer/config/SecurityConfig.java

The security filter is already setup. So, how to resolve this error and have my `contractTest` running properly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues on the BaseClass.

1. If you are using the latest Spring Boot, use `@SpringBootTest` is enough. No need the `@ExtendedWith`
2. Use a Mock env, set webEnvironment = Mock
3. If you decided to use RestAssuredMockMvc, you should use this mockMvc instead of the standard MockMVC in your tests.
4. The `Mockito.reset` in cleanup is no need at all.

In a WebMvc project, exclude the `UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` and `SecurityAutoConfiguration` in your test context, check [my example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-webmvc-jwt-sample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/VehicleControllerTest.java#L29-L34).

In a WebFlux project, just exclude `ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` and `ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration` and `ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration`(if oauth2 resource server is enabled.) on your testing codes.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class, ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
class YourTest{
}
```

Or test web controller.

```java
@WebFluxTest(controller=YourController.calss, excludeAutoConfigurations = {ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class, ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
class YourTest{
}
```

I have created a simple Microservice sample several years ago, which used Spring Cloud Contract and Pact to implement the CDC pattern in the API testing and verify, check [spring-microservice-sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample).

Comment: After I added the annotations, the error still exists... I tested both the Reactive and non-reactive annotations...

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your codes, you mixed a lot of test features. Please read the [Testing part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing) to get started.

Comment: And of course, I hope you have read the  [official Spring Cloud Contract workshop](https://spring-cloud-samples.github.io/spring-cloud-contract-samples/workshops.htmlc) to get to know how to use Spring Cloud Contract.

Comment: Agree mixed a lot of test features. I am having some trouble separating the integration test and the functional test elements...  I wanted to not create the same POJOs again and again. If you were I, how would you separate them?? Do you have any advice??

Comment: your sample repo looks great. Let me study study

Comment: This answer solves the autoconfiguration related to spring security but it is short of solving my issue in the spring cloud contract with Kafka...